# Fluid Layout: Divs with height:auto and dynamic content

Tags: jquery, css, layout, wordpress-theming

I am stuck at trying to accomplish the following, basically I have a series of custom type blog posts that will be displaying on my custom template in wordpress, these blog posts will be "boxes" with variable heights depending on their content.

The problem that I need to resolve it to make it so that the second row or the following row will flush the 3 next divs so that they are just below of each of the div above itself rather than vertical aligning the div to the highest div of previous row.

So let's say my first row of div, contains div1 with height = 120px, div2 with height = 100px and then div3 with height = 160px. Then my second row of divs should display 20px below each of those ones regardless of the height of the first row of divs.

What's the best approach to do this? If someone could provide me with an example, either CSS or Jquery. It would be appreciate it !

Comment: Sounds like you want one of the "fluid column" layouts, where each column stacks downward independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your wordpress theme you could use php. First build your columns and put them all in the same row:

```
<html>
<body>  
<?
define('NUMBEROFCOLUMNS',3);
define('NUMBEROFTEXTS',15);
$dummytext = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a neque vehicula nunc sollicitudin ultricies. In turpis arcu, tincidunt vel malesuada quis, tincidunt sit amet nisi. Etiam vitae lorem arcu. Proin sit amet nisi mi. Fusce mollis risus quis magna tristique viverra. Etiam varius posuere.';


$columns = array();
/* initialize */
for($i=0; $i<NUMBEROFCOLUMNS; $i++)
{
    $columns[$i]='';
}   
for($i=0; $i<NUMBEROFTEXTS; $i++)
{
    $columns[$i%NUMBEROFCOLUMNS] .= '<div style="margin-top:20px;border: red 1px solid;">'.substr($dummytext,0,rand(100,300)).'</div>';
}

?>
<div class="row">   
<?
$width =round(100/NUMBEROFCOLUMNS);
foreach($columns as $column)
{
    ?>
        <div style="width: <?=$width?>%;float:left;"><?=$column?></div>
    <?
}   
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @bass your code is simply and nice, thanks! but the problem I am having now it to be able slidedown some of the content. Basically if I click on one of the boxes, another div displaying detailed information about the post should show up below the box that was clicked and it would be the width of the entire row and with flexible height depending on its content. and the row below with the rest of rows should be all shifted down..any ideas? I tried using the slidedown for jquery but I keep on getting the "Expanded" div kind of top of existent content and the other content doesnt slidedown.

Comment: This should be a new question maybe? You can do this with javascript / jquery. One solution seems to be to split your content with javascript in two parts with columns based on the click. So you will get `<div class="row"></div>slider<div class="row"></div>`.
Or add you slider with an absolute position and move the divs under it. You can do this with jquery too. Use offset() en position(). See http://jsfiddle.net/bassjobsen/9ZW9y/ for some example code. Note you will have to refactor this code before use it in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure these aren't the answers you're looking for. It sounds like you need to layout your content like Pintrest does, if I understood you correctly.

I've recently used [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html) which stacks elements in a grid and is very versitile.

I used it on my own website which is responsive/mobile friendly and it works great, I revert to simple full width stacks for the smaller views. To do this I simply disable the plugin on smaller screens and modified with css from there.

Comment: thanks @Jamil I tried Masonry but the problem I am having now is that once I get the boxes arrange as I want but now when I try to open up another div, basically when a box is clicked it should expand detail content of what the box was clicked on. and the row of divs below should all shift down.... have not had any luck achieving this using Masonry Column Shift

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Fluid Layout](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids). Do not use px, use ems or %.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into using a responsive layout. Some good things to look at, and develop from might be:

[Foundation Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com)
[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)

Or simply, you can use @media queries.

Regards,
Matt